# Search/Query a ListView and print results to new ListView

Tags: c#, linq, listview, search

I want to search an existing ListView that has FOUR columns and print the results of the search in an entirely new ListView. Here is what I have thus far:

```
private void qryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var results = listResx.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
      .Where(x => x.Text.Contains(textQuery.Text));

    foreach (var d in results)
    {
        listQuery.Items.Add(d.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with existing solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to search in all four columns of each item than something like this should to the trick:

```
var results = listResx.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
      .Where(x => x.Subitems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                  .Any(si => si.Text.Contains(textQuery.Text)
            );
```

`results` would then contain ListViewItems where the query text matched any of the sub-items. And as far as I recall, the sub-items's collection includes the item's text as well.

To insert those as full list items in the other list view you will have to create a new ListViewItem for each item in the results enumeration because you can't insert the same ListViewItem in two different list views at the same time:

```
foreach (var d in results)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    foreach(ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem si in d.SubItems)
    {
        lvi.SubItems.Add(si.Text);
    }
    listQuery.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That got me one step closer but I would like to display the entire row if any of the sub-items met the query. As it stands right now all that is displaying is the first column of the row that met the query.

Comment: please see the update. you have to create a new list view item for each result because you can't have the same listviewitem in two lists at the same time..

Comment: 'ListViewSubItem does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument.'